# What is the most performant way to check if Content Notes is enabled in a org?

Tags: apex, dynamic-apex, contentnote

Is there a more performant way to dynamically detect if [Content Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notes_admin_overview.htm) is enabled?

I see that `getGlobalDescribe` can be used to check the presence `ContentNote`, if it present then is enabled. Usually, the time is around 400-500ms on the first call and very little in subsequent calls - around 40ms. So, I see caching reducing the CPU Time consumption for subsequent calls but if the initial call could be reduced, that would be even better.

Getting rid of the describe call is a possibility if is reliable and more performant.

e.g.:

```
Map<String, SobjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Boolean isContentNotesEnabled = gd.get('ContentNote') != null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using Schema.ContentNote instead of just ContentNote. Note that a developer could still use the class named Schema, so you'd also make sure there's no Schema class:

```
if(Type.forName('Schema') == null) {
  if(Type.forName('Schema.ContentNote') != null) {
    // We have ContentNote!
  }
} else {
  if(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('ContentNote') != null) {
    // We have ContentNote!
  }
}
```

Note that if someone defines a Schema class, we have to fallback to the slower (500ms) method, as this is always safe, but can use the much faster (<1ms, I think) method otherwise.

Comment: All of this trouble because Salesforce doesn't have a way that performant and native to inform code if Content Notes are enabled.

Comment: That is helpful @sfdcfox, thanks a million.

Comment: Was just revisiting this, do you think is worth doing `if(Type.forName('Schema', 'ContentNote') != null) {` to avoid the both initial if statements?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a more direct way, but there's a more efficient way to do what your check does:

```
Type contentNoteType = Type.forName('ContentNote');
System.debug(contentNoteType != null && contentNoteType.newInstance() instanceof SObject);
```

This saves you getting the global schema.

Comment: That is a very interesting approach, could not it stop to work if there is a class named `ContentNote`?

Comment: Only if the class called ContentNote didn't have a default constructor. If it does, that code would still get the right answer because it's checking the type of the new instance. If it doesn't have a default constructor, an exception is thrown (which I guess you could catch)

Comment: Got you, the problem is the collision, because if it happens then it is back to square one to check if ContentNote is a valid sObject (even catching the exception).